# Data Manipulation in excel using python

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to do excel manipulations using python, Trying to do the following divison operation but the formula function is not returning the result
Given below the manipulation statement 
`sheet2['B' + str(l)]` has got value as 40 and expected o/p should be 5:

```
sheetout['F' + str(l)] = "=(sheet2['B' + str(l)]/8)"
```

Comment: Can you add code? -  Check if these could help - http://www.python-excel.org/ .  https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Should it be `"=B1/8"` instead of `"=(sheet2['B' + str(l)]/8)"`?